# Is there an internal variable or something like it that indicates when all the Rest API calls in a SPFx webpart are done?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I have about 200+ Rest API calls in a SPFx webpart (TypeScript and JSON). Most of them are asynchronized. Everything is working fine. I just need to know when all the calls are done so I can save the results without missing any values. I know I could set flags when calls are done and then check them and save if they are all true, etc. But working with 200+ flags doesn't sound very efficient. Is there a better way to do this? An internal variable perhaps that indicates when everything is settled? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) or [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).
They are all methods used to resolve multiple requests and handle the return value.
Another blog for your reference:
[How to solve callback hell](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deal-with-nested-callbacks-and-avoid-callback-hell-1bc8dc4a2012/)

Comment: I'll take a look at those. Thanks.